# Excel 2007 SUMIF Command - Is there a way to add cells that contain data (letters and numbers)?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Is there any way to get Excel to look at cells that contain data? I've been using >0 but this doesn't pick up the contents of the cell if if starts with letters. I'm trying to do a SUMIF command.

Comment: To clarify... Is there numerical data also in these cells or are you trying to sum alphanumeric values? Just wanting to make sure...

Comment: There is numerical data also. The formula looks like this - =SUMIF(H6:H234,">0",C6:C236) but the greater than zero doesn't work for cells that start with letters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want to do exactly but if you are interested in the numerical value of the cell, you may have to use `val()` function on the cell but if you only want to see if there is something in the cell (alpha or numeric), you should compare it with a blank cell or empty cell using `isblank()` or `isempty()`. As you are comparing with `>0`, I guess `isblank()` is your best choice.

Comment: Hi there. I am trying to add the contents of a different column to the one that contains the data. Is there such a thing as "is not blank?"

Comment: It's been solved! Thanks for all of your help. The way to do it is to use <>. Thanks again.